# Float CSS attribute causing parent div not to inherit height?

Tags: html, css

I have an element in a div set to `float: right` however, it causes the outermost div not to wrap around. This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W792X/5/) for it.

I'm trying to get the submit button to float right within the div but setting that attribute seems to cause it to break. How can I get a parent element to wrap a floated element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. The parent div should have `overflow: hidden;`. That will make it contain any floated elements in it.

Answer (score 7):

Set the container to `overflow: hidden`, and [it'll wrap!](http://jsfiddle.net/W792X/10/)

Answer (score 2):

Set "overflow: hidden;" on the parent. This will cause it to contain any floated elements within.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<br style="clear: both;" />` after the floating div.

Comment: I'd use <div> instead of <br>.

Comment: Agreed - safari won't treat a `<br style="clear:both;" />` properly - you have to use a div if you want it to work across browsers

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="element">
          <label></label>
          <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Post Assessment">
          <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

MDN on this case says this:

> Note: If an element contains only floated elements, its height
> collapses to nothing. If you want it to always be able to resize, so
> that it contains floating elements inside it, set the value of the
> element's display property to flow-root.
>
> ```
> #container {
>   display: flow-root;
> }
> ```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

On the `overflow` method they say the following:

> The problem with using `overflow` to create a new BFC is that the
> `overflow` property is meant for telling the browser how you wish to
> deal with overflowing content. There are some occasions in which you
> will find you get unwanted scrollbars or clipped shadows when you use
> this property purely to create a BFC. In addition, it is potentially
> not very readable for a future developer, as it may not be obvious why
> you used `overflow` for this purpose. If you do this, it would be a
> good idea to comment the code to explain.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flow_layout/Introduction_to_formatting_contexts

So I would prefer the `diplay: flow-root` method.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
text-align:right
```

Instead of float:right