# Identical divs not stacking rather overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div that is going to hold some content and i will be replicating the div several times below.

When i repeat the div multiple times, i see the content overlapping each other and not stacking.

On inspecting, i can see the height of the container is not set. Will the height not get set depending on the content inside the div? I was under that impression and not sure where i am now.

Here's my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/5jq52/2/

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5">
<div class="Mycontainer">
    <div class="Item1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="Pic">
    </div>
    <div class="Item2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="Pic">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Mycontainer">
    <div class="Item1">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="Pic">
    </div>
    <div class="Item2">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="Pic">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks a ton for reading and resolving. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be setting the `position:absolute` on the wrappers. This removes your content from the semantic flow of the document altogether, and the remaining content will flow to the top to fill the gap, hence the 'overlap' effect.

**[Here's a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/4cy7b/)** of your situation with `position:absolute;` commented out.

If you wanted to float the images in each container side by side without specifying a height for the parent container, [you need to apply `overflow:hidden` to the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990832/float-css-attribute-causing-parent-div-not-to-inherit-height).

Comment: yeah i sort of understand the problem. I have lot of items inside the container. For simplicity, I've listed very minimal divs here. Will turn all absolute to relative and update here. 

Not sure if overflow: hidden alone would work. Seen in few places where if two items have to be filled in a div side by side, people give float: left to both.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5jq52/3/ overflow: hidden solves the problem while i'm not able to put the Item1 and Item2 side by side :(

Comment: @GopinathR it won't float for a few reasons. 1) You have the `width` of each `<div>` set to 50%, then have applied a 1px border on top of that, which equals `(100% width + 2px)` or greater than 100%. Objects won't float if there isn't room. 2) You also don't need to apply `position:relative` to the elements, the default `position:static` does the trick :). To apply `position:static`, just remove the `position` property altogether.

Comment: You are the One! I had some ten divs positioned within the container and i've somehow made them all settle. Now the containers are stacking. Thanks a tonne. Marking yours the answer. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You actually have several different problems going on. The reason your divs are appearing over one another and not stacking is because you've specified `position: absolute;` when you should use `position: relative;`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the `position` attribute of them to `position: absolute` that way it would not mesh over the other? You may need to create other div's to get the result you are looking for. I hope I have helped!

Comment: thanks. i set min-height to container and was able to stack/displace the containers. Thing is there could be some more content below the images. You can imagine the facebook comment section. I want the Mycontainer to grow tall based on its content. am i making sense?

Comment: @GopinathR Yes that makes sense, you would need more divs for this, do you have a fiddle that works, I could possibly mess around with it?

Comment: @GopinathR I've added a Fiddle showing this in the comment above